# Can internal ip addresses of the worker machines be used to connect the worker to rabbitmq queue?

Tags: django, server, rabbitmq, celery

the two machines the "master rabbitmq queue handler" and the "worker machine are servers of same platform (i.e digitalocean)".

Can their internal ips be used to connect them? If yes will it be any faster than the external ip connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a network/sysadmin question question than a programming one but anyway:

As long as one machine can access the other thru it's "internal ip" (I assume you mean a local private ip) and there's nothing blocking connections (firewall etc) on those ips, then yes of course it will work. Just note that because two machines belong to the same hosting company doesn't mean they are connected to the same local network (are they physically in the same datacenter ?).

As wether using the internal ip will or not be faster, it depends on the local network, the ethernet cards etc - it's *usually* faster when both servers are on the same local network indeed, but it's not garanteed either.

Comment: That means i should test the communication over the internal ips.If it exists, After that may or maynot there will be any gain in speed. ohkay.

Comment: Not only "test the communication" - I mean, a mere "ping" is not enough, you also have to 1/ make sure the (local) ip matches the expected machine (local ips are local, so two local network can use the same local ip each for a different machine - that's the whole point of local ips actually) and 2/ you can actually _connect_ on the desired port on the other machine - it migh have firewall rules forbidding connections on those port on the local ip.